# Создание архива для отправки в AppStore

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, appstore

Почему моя программа весила 1.3 Гб до создания архива(в Xcode) и отправки в AppStore, после отправки в магазине показывает что весит 3 Гб. Кто знает как исправить это и возможно ли вообще?

Comment: В Приложения -> Действия -> нажать на сборку -> Размер файлов для App Store -> что показывает для разных устройств?

Comment: А что такого вы туда поместили? 1,3 Гб - долго качать, не смотря на лимит в 4 Гб (https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=02122015a )

Answer (score 0):

При компиляции проекта xCode добавляет в него необходимые библиотеки и пр.

Плюс в зависимости от количества устройств, для которых данное приложение будет доступным эти дополнительные данные, по сути, дублируются.

Например: проект приложения для iPhone и iPad весит всего 1,3 Мб, но его архив (Xcode Archive) получился — 298,5 МБ!

А его дистрибутивы (в iTunes Connect можно посмотреть) будут весить по отдельности:

- универсальный - 6,2 Мб (после установки размер программы - 15,1 Мб)
- iPad 4 поколения - 3,1 Мб (7 Мб)
- iPhone X - 2,8 Мб (7,9 Мб)
- и др....

Если суммировать все эти размеры, как раз 300 Мб примерно и получатся.